# How to accept a meeting invite via keyboard shortcut in Outlook 2007

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a keyboard shortcut to accept a meeting invite in Outlook 2007 (or another edition)?

If so, what is it?

Comment: @CharlieRB - the answer there does work: thanks for finding and linking it here :)

Comment: then should this be kept live ? why not delete this ? else will flag this duplicate and at then will close. @warren you already know the review queue is huge.. what you say

Comment: @BaljeetsinghSucharia - let's just close as a duplicate, given that the original was *specifically* for version 2010, and this was asked for 2007 :)

Comment: :) Lol , you proved that you are around SO for long time ! have flagged duplicate, happy weekend..

Comment: @BaljeetsinghSucharia sounds good =D

Comment: @warren Question for your question : shortcut to accept meeting request from where ? when you have opened the meeting request OR when you are checking inbox and from mail list you want to accept ?

Comment: @BaljeetsinghSucharia - either and/or both

Comment: just a thought , do you think and/or both should be updated to question to remove the duplicate flag ? assuming that was your intention

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMO, there are **two ways you can accept** a meeting request.

1. when you are browsing list mail (and invite isn't opened)
2. wen you have opened the invite

**for 1)**
When the meeting invite is the focused email

- press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> this will open the context menu(right click menu of invite)
- now press <kbd>C</kbd> again <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- now use common response key

**for 2)**

As you already know ,

- can use  <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to navigate to ribbon
- <kbd>C</kbd> to do the click effect on pull out accept response option
- now use common response key

**Common Response Key**

both ways post you select accept you can use  any of following to respond

- <kbd>E</kbd> Edit the response before sending.
- <kbd>S</kbd> Send the response now.
- <kbd>D</kbd> Don't send a response.

Comment: Cross posted on blog with some images to understand better : http://blog.baljeetsingh.net/2014/03/how-to-accept-outlook-meeting-invite.html

Comment: @ScottH question is based on outlook 2007 so that isn't changed having said that I have office version 2017 it the same shortcut keys work.